# Deleting MySQL records at a certain time

Tags: php, mysql, time, records

I have a database set up on a shared hosting plan that has a set of records that I would like to have delete automatically at the date and time that a user has entered into the *exptime* column. How would I go about setting this up? I am very new to this so I need step by step directions.

Comment: You probably want to set up a cron job to do this at regular intervals.

Comment: cron jobs or [mysql events](https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-mysql-events/)

Comment: Do you have a php script hitting the database with any regularity? If so, you could have a php function that does a quick `DELETE FROM table WHERE exptime < CURTIME()` run, and just trigger that php function just before any function(s) that read records from the table.

Comment: How would I write a cron job for this. I am using the table closings and exptime for when I would like the record to expire. I would like to to expire based off of a date and time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to use cron, I would set up a php file that selects all the records that are less than or equal to *exptime* and then delete them, then run that php file either every night, or every minute, or whatever fits your needs

Comment: I am able to add a cron job. How would I go about creating the php for this? The records are in closings and the time for them to expire is in exptime.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I would like to to delete the record based on a certain date and time. I can run it every minute.

Comment: So you would create a specific php file (maybe record_delete.php) where you would run a query to get all rows (with a unique identifier) that have an expiration date, status, whatever meet your criteria. Then, for each row, you can issue a delete query where the unique identifier = the item you're currently looping through. Then you just set up a cron job to run "php /path/to/record_delete.php" every minute

Comment: I am new to php as well. I am using id as null with auto increment. I am also using name, status, category and exptime. This is all sorted in a table called closings. Could you please help me write the php for this?